# Los 2 bucles que hago me deberían retornar lo mismo pero no pasa

Tags: c++, array, funciones, punteros

En el primer bucle que recorre con `++` de la función me retorna 29 y la segunda que recorre con `+i` me retorna 30 , pero ambas deberían retornar 29. ¿Que estoy haciendo?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sumaElementos(int a[],int tam){
    int acum=0;
    int *p;
    p = &a[0];

    //BUCLE 1

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        acum+=*p++;
    } //RETORNA 29


    //BUCLE 2
    
    /*for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        acum+=*p+i;
    }*/ //RETORNA 30
      

    return acum;
    
}

int main(){

    int arreglo[5]={4,9,6,7,3};

    cout<<sumaElementos(arreglo,5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en el segundo bucle falta un parentesis cuando se hace la suma, que indica que se fije en la posicion en memoria de lo que esta dentro del parentesis, el código del bucle seria asi:

```
for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
    acum += *(p+i);
}
return acum;
```

En el primer bucle estas aumentando en 1 la posicion en memoria del vector en cada iteracion, en el segundo lo que haces es que tomas la primera posicion y le sumas el valor de i para llegar a la posicion deseada, cuando haces esto, para que C++ no se confunda tenes que ponerlo entre parentesis con el asterisco fuera para indicar que mire en la posicion de memoria de lo que esta dentro de los parentesis